# How to check a valid boost asio CompletionToken?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-asio, completionhandler

I'm writing Boost.Asio style async function that takes `CompletionToken` argument.
The argument can be function, function object, lambda expression, future, awaitable, etc.

`CompletionToken` is template parameter. If I don't restrict the argument, the function could match unexpected parameter such as `int`. So I want to write some restriction using `std::enable_if`. (My environment is C++17).

If `CompletionToken` takes parameters, then I can use `std::is_invocable` for checking.

See `f1` in my example code.

However, I got a problem. If `CompletionToken` takes no parameters, then `boost::asio::use_future` makes an error.

See `f2` in my example code.

After some of try and error, I got my solution. That is concatenating `std::is_invocable` and `use_future_t` checking by OR (`||`).

See `f3` in my example code.

But it is not so elegant. In addition, I'm not sure other features supported by Boost.Asio e.g.) use_awaitable_t requires similar direct matching check.

I tried to find Boost.Asio provides type traits or predicate such as `is_completion_token`, but I couldn't find it.

Is there any better way to checking `CompletionToken`?

Godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/sPeMo1GEK

Complete Code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// Callable T takes one argument
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<T, int>>* = nullptr
>
void f1(T) {
}

// Callable T takes no argument
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<T>>* = nullptr
>
void f2(T) {
}


template <template <typename...> typename, typename>
struct is_instance_of : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename T, typename U>
struct is_instance_of<T, T<U>> : std::true_type {};

// Callable T takes no argument
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_invocable_v<T> ||
        is_instance_of<boost::asio::use_future_t, T>::value
    >* = nullptr
>
void f3(T) {
}

int main() {
    // no error
    f1([](int){});
    f1(boost::asio::use_future);

    // same rule as f1 but use_future got compile error
    f2([](){});
    f2(boost::asio::use_future); // error

    // a little complecated typechecking, then no error
    f3([](){});
    f3(boost::asio::use_future);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Output of x86-64 clang 13.0.1 (Compiler #1)
<source>:45:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f2'
    f2(boost::asio::use_future); // error
    ^~
<source>:17:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_invocable_v<boost::asio::use_future_t<std::allocator<void>>>' was not satisfied [with T = boost::asio::use_future_t<>]
void f2(T) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have c++20 concepts, look below. Otherwise, read on.

When you want to correctly implement the async-result protocol using Asio, you would use the `async_result` trait, or the `async_initiate` as documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html#:%7E:text=A%20key%20goal%20of%20Boost,API%20surface%20of%20the%20library.).

This should be a reliable key for SFINAE. The template arguments to `async_result` include the token *and* the completion signature(s):

[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/srqbcj18E)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::async_result;

template <typename Token,
          typename R = typename async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(int)>::return_type>
void f1(Token&&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

template <typename Token,
          typename R = typename async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void()>::return_type>
void f2(Token&&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

int main() {
    auto cb1 = [](int) {};
    f1(cb1);
    f1(boost::asio::use_future);
    f1(boost::asio::use_awaitable);
    f1(boost::asio::detached);
    f1(boost::asio::as_tuple(boost::asio::use_awaitable));

    auto cb2 = []() {};
    f2(cb2);
    f2(boost::asio::use_future);
    f2(boost::asio::use_awaitable);
    f2(boost::asio::detached);
    f2(boost::asio::as_tuple(boost::asio::use_awaitable));
}
```

Already prints

```
void f1(Token&&) [with Token = main()::<lambda(int)>&; R = void]
void f1(Token&&) [with Token = const boost::asio::use_future_t<>&; R = std::future<int>]
void f1(Token&&) [with Token = const boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<>&; R = boost::asio::awaitable<int, boost::asio::any_io_executor>]
void f1(Token&&) [with Token = const boost::asio::detached_t&; R = void]
void f1(Token&&) [with Token = boost::asio::as_tuple_t<boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<> >; R = boost::asio::awaitable<std::tuple<int>, boost::asio::any_io_executor>]
void f2(Token&&) [with Token = main()::<lambda()>&; R = void]
void f2(Token&&) [with Token = const boost::asio::use_future_t<>&; R = std::future<void>]
void f2(Token&&) [with Token = const boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<>&; R = boost::asio::awaitable<void, boost::asio::any_io_executor>]
void f2(Token&&) [with Token = const boost::asio::detached_t&; R = void]
void f2(Token&&) [with Token = boost::asio::as_tuple_t<boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<> >; R = boost::asio::awaitable<std::tuple<>, boost::asio::any_io_executor>]
```

### C++20 Concepts

Now keep in mind the above is "too lax" due to partial template instantiation. Some parts of `async_result` aren't actually used. That means that `f2(cb1);` [will actually compile](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/MPEbzvazj).

The linked docs even include the C++20 `completion_token_for<Sig>` concept that allows you to be precise at no effort: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/MPMsKGf6z)**

```
template <boost::asio::completion_token_for<void(int)> Token> void f1(Token&&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

template <boost::asio::completion_token_for<void()> Token> void f2(Token&&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}
```

### Otherwise

In practice you would always follow the Asio recipe, and that guarantees that all parts are used. Apart from the example in the documentation, you can search [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+async_result)

Example:

```
template <typename Token>
typename asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code, int)>::return_type
async_f1(Token&& token) {
    auto init = [](auto completion) {
        auto timer =
            std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(boost::asio::system_executor{}, 1s);
        std::thread(
            [timer](auto completion) {
                error_code ec;
                timer->wait(ec);
                std::move(completion)(ec, 42);
            },
            std::move(completion))
            .detach();
    };

    return asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code, int)>::initiate(
        init, std::forward<Token>(token));
}
```

Comment: thank you. When I create `async_result<...>::initiate(...)` in the function `f1()` and `f2()` , and I pass invalid token such as int, then I got error as `/usr/include/boost/asio/compose.hpp:380:5: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer`. I can get the calling point from the error log (like back trace). It is not so difficult so it is an acceptable solution. In my actual code uses `async_compose`...

Comment: ...That behave similar to `async_result<>::initiate`. But the error happnens a little deeper point of the asio library. I'm looking for the way to make error at `f1()` and `f2()` using SFINAE. I added invalid token to your example https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KT57hzK3o but no error reported.
If I could write a good SFINAE at `f1()` and `f2()` point, it would be nice. What do you think?

Comment: I guess that Boost.Asio doesn't provide a way to check token validation for user's async functions like `f1()` and `f2()` 's argument token. But thier implementation is typically use `async_result<>::initiate` or `async_compose`. And they check token and if user passed invalid token, the error is reported. The error is easu enough to understand and easy to find calling point. So Boost.Asio think that the checking at `f1()` and `f2()` is not needed. That's my understanding, so far.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand something. Only when I use `asio::async_result<...)>::return_type` as return type, the calling point is included compile error log. If I replaced it with `auto` that means no check, then calling point is disappeared from the compile error log. So using `asio::async_result<...)>::return_type` is the solution I want to know. Thanks again.

Comment: "I guess that Boost.Asio doesn't provide a way to check token validation" - what's wrong with `asio::completion_token_for`? I guess you can probably find a C++17 friendly implementation (detail) that you can reuse.

Comment: About using `return_type` - yes that's what I warned about in the answer _[""too lax" due to partial template instantiation. Some parts of async_result aren't actually used"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74431093/how-to-check-a-valid-boost-asio-completiontoken/74433892#74433892:~:text=the%20above%20is-,%22too%20lax%22%20due%20to%20partial%20template%20instantiation.%20Some%20parts%20of%20async_result%20aren%27t%20actually%20used,-.%20That%20means%20that). Mind you, you don't need to worry since `async_compose` _by definition_  instantiates the entire class.

Comment: I didn't check `asio::completion_token_for` implementation because my environment is not C++20 but C++17. I will take a look it and try to port C++17 implementation. Perhaps, it might not be able to. Just my guessing that if there is a way to implement `asio::completion_token_for` compatible SFINAE friendly type_traits , Boost.Asio would provide it as a part of the library. Anyway I will try it.

Comment: I don't see why they would provide it, because it adds no value. The reason a concept adds value is precisely because it may lead to clearer error messages. If you can explicitly force early checks you can always make that into a static_assert that makes it "easier" for your users (so instead of SFINAE, which leads to ... complicated compiler diagnostics). Mind you, the diagnostics will always be complicated for C++17, but you *can* potentially add the static_assert to "help"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249648/discussion-between-takatoshi-kondo-and-sehe).